# Separate numberings in two equation environments

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'd like to have two equation-like environments, with separate numbering, and easily use them inside various amsmath environments.

Inspired by an answer by Egreg to [Clone of the `amsmath` equation environment with different spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409044/clone-of-the-amsmath-equation-environment-with-different-spacing), I wrote

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{savedequation} \newcounter{myhypo}

\newcommand{\setmyhypo}{%
   \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
   \setcounter{equation}{\value{myhypo}}%
   \renewcommand\theequation{$H_\arabic{equation}$}%
}

\newcommand{\unsetmyhypo}{%
   \setcounter{myhypo}{\value{equation}}%
   \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
}

\newenvironment{hypothesis}{%
   \setmyhypo%
   \begin{equation}%
}{%
   \end{equation}%
   \unsetmyhypo%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{hypothesis}   \label{test_1} a=b \end{hypothesis}

\begin{gather}
   \label{test_2} c=d \\
   \setmyhypo
   \notag e=f \\
   \label{test_3} h=i
   \unsetmyhypo 
\end{gather}

\setmyhypo 
\begin{gather}
   \label{test_4} j=k \\
   \notag l=m 
\end{gather}
\unsetmyhypo

\eqref{test_1}, \eqref{test_2} and \eqref{test_4} work but not \eqref{test_3}.

\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to use both equation-like environments inside the same gather (it may be cleaner for alignment purpose)?

Edit: refinements:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setmyhypo}{%
  \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{myhypo}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{$H_{\arabic{equation}}$}%
  \tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno%
}

\newcommand{\unsetmyhypo}{%
  \setcounter{myhypo}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}%
  \tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: PS: I still don't understand how to put automatically compiled code samples.

Comment: Regarding producing output that can be posted here, this has a number of suggestions:  [Compile a LaTeX document into a PNG image that's as short as possible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11866)

Comment: @barbara: Thanks. I thought some here were able to enter code that is automatically compiled by tex.stackexchange.com online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\tag` (together with code that does the necessary stuff).

I made some changes to the code, please check them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{savedequation}
\newcounter{myhypo}
\renewcommand\themyhypo{\ensuremath{\mathrm{H}_{\arabic{myhypo}}}}

\newcommand{\setmyhypo}{%
  \setcounter{savedequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{myhypo}}%
  \renewcommand\theequation{\ensuremath{\mathrm{H}_{\arabic{equation}}}}%
}

\newcommand{\unsetmyhypo}{%
  \setcounter{myhypo}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{savedequation}}%
}

\newenvironment{hypothesis}{%
   \setmyhypo
   \begin{equation}%
}{%
   \end{equation}%
   \unsetmyhypo
   \ignorespacesafterend
}
\newcommand{\hypoline}{\stepcounter{myhypo}\tag{\themyhypo}}

\begin{document}

\begin{hypothesis}\label{test_1}
a=b
\end{hypothesis}

\begin{gather}
  c=d \label{test_2} \\
  e=f \notag \\
  h=i \hypoline \label{test_3} \\
  u=v
\end{gather}

\setmyhypo 
\begin{gather}
  j=k \label{test_4} \\
  l=m \notag
\end{gather}
\unsetmyhypo

\eqref{test_1}, \eqref{test_2} and \eqref{test_4} work and also does \eqref{test_3}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed cleaner. I did not use \tag initially because I also use hyperref and I was not sure it would work correctly with hyperref, but I do not see why not : I'm going to test it now.

Comment: Ah, its the requirement to change the side of the tag `\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno`, that I foolishly added later, that I don't see how to make work properly... It does not seem to work if called inside an amsmath environment. However it was not so important.

Comment: Using your command `\hypoline`, there is no more real need of a specific hypothesis environment, nor of my commands `\setmyhypo`, `\unsetmyhypo`, nor of counter `savedequation`.

Comment: @dominique Yes, that's right.